# React Native - Deployment Build Failure

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I'm trying deploy my app today but there's a **build failure** that I couldn't figure out, it shows after I enter "gradlew assembleRelease" in my terminal.

[image]

Comment: It's only a warning it's not blocking you from creating the keystore. But you can try and migrate it to the standard format by running the command in the warning. (don't forget to  replace the file names with your file names)

Comment: The command is exactly what you should execute (even the files seem to be replaced with your file names)

Comment: I think @HedShafran is correct because I just look at my file folder right now and there is a "my-release-key.keystore" file.

Comment: Yep. Everything should work normally with this keystore file regardless of the warning(recommendation).

Comment: I got a Build Failure, I'll edit my post

Comment: Did you do everything as instructed here? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

Comment: yes, I solved it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by checking the code that the docs will ask you to do, in my case I accidentally erased a single space and then the error occur. So for the future developers, make sure you write the code properly.